# Why is the URL parameter I want to retrieve not fully displayed?

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

I am tracking URLs with **"posName"** parameters like:

example.com?posName=**Content+&+Community+Manager+(H/F)**

But my code returns **"Content"** only:

```
function () {
    var uri = document.location.href;
    var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri);
    var url = new URL(uri_dec);
    var posName= url.searchParams.get("posName");
    return posName;
}
```

How can I get the full parameter?

**EDIT:**
I have another URL like:

exemple.com?posName=**Club+&+Animator+(H/F)**

And the code returns the full parameter... So is it the **length** of the parameter which causes this issue?

Comment: Well that's an invalid URI - you'd need to encode the `&` where you're sending the data like `%26`.

Comment: Try to follow the example in https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuricomponent.asp

Comment: Good point... Is it possible to encode 1 element of the url only ?

Comment: I tried another approach with regex :  var regex = (/(?=posName=)(.*)&/g) //                
    var posName = uri.match(regex).... but it is returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason you have no control over what's in the `window.location.href`, you can solve this quite easily via regex:

```js
function getPosName(uri) {
    let match = uri.match(/(?<=posName=)(.+?)(?=\&\w+?\=|$)/); 
    return match[1]; 
}

console.log(getPosName( "xemple.com?posName=Content+&+Community+Manager+(H/F)")); //Content+&+Community+Manager+(H/F)
console.log(getPosName( "exemple.com?posName=Club+&+Animator+(H/F)")); //Club+&+Animator+(H/F)
console.log(getPosName( "exemple.com?posName=Club+&+Animator+(H/F)&test=1")); // Club+&+Animator+(H/F)
```

Regex explanation:

> `(?=postName=)` lookbehind to find `postName=` to start the match
>
> `(.+?)` matches anything up to the lookahead pattern below
>
> `(?=\&\w+?\=|$)` loohahead pattern for literal `&` followed by some text of any length from 1 onwards `\w+?` followed by `=`. All that, or we're at the end of the input string, denoted by `$`

**Update**

The regex lookbehind is *relatively* new. If the browser or app doesn't support the regex lookbehind (e.g. Google Tag Manager currently), try this workaround instead:

```js
function getPosName(uri) {
    let match = uri.match(/posName=(.+?)(?=\&\w+?\=|$)/);
    return match[1];
}

console.log(getPosName( "xemple.com?posName=Content+&+Community+Manager+(H/F)")); //Content+&+Community+Manager+(H/F)
console.log(getPosName( "exemple.com?posName=Club+&+Animator+(H/F)")); //Club+&+Animator+(H/F)
console.log(getPosName( "exemple.com?posName=Club+&+Animator+(H/F)&test=1")); // Club+&+Animator+(H/F)
```

Comment: Nice regex... however when using it with a script in Google tag Manager, it returns this error : ": Cannot convert ECMASCRIPT_2018 feature "RegExp Lookbehind" to targeted output language."

Is GTM not accepting new regex features ?

Comment: While waiting for GTM to upgrade, we can use the workaround in my updated answer :D

Comment: Thanks.. i needed to adapt a little bit for GTM ("var" instead of "let") but it works fine !

Answer (score 5):

I've modified your function to accept the URI as an argument. You need to encode the parameter before appending it to the query string (we can't see this code here). The decodeURIComponent in your function is also not necessary.

```js
function getPosName (URI) {
    //var uri_dec = decodeURIComponent(uri);
    var url = new URL(URI);
    var posName = url.searchParams.get("posName");
  return posName;
}

console.log("Using your current URI:", getPosName("http://exemple.com?posName=Content+&+Community+Manager+(H/F)"))

const encodedParam = encodeURIComponent("Content & Community Manager (H/F)")
console.log("Encoded Parameter:", encodedParam)
const wellFormedURI = `http://exemple.com?posName=${encodedParam}`
console.log("Well Formed URI:", wellFormedURI)
console.log("Using well formed URI:", getPosName(wellFormedURI))
```